# How to toggle between different windows in Pages (Mac)?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, iwork-pages

Normally I use Cmd ` (the key above the Tab key), it is perfect for most of applications and Finder, except Pages. If I have 2 documents editing at the same time and want to switch back and forth between them, the shortcut above simply zooms out the current document a little bit. Does it exist a combination shortcut only for Pages?

Comment: Is this on a US keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> does not work for you, most users have suggest using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> as a workaround to this, especially on keyboards that are not using a US Keyboard Layout. (I had to use the ~ for the first one there, or else it would have put my entire sentence as a code)

You can also review a full list of Pages [keyboard shortcuts here.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23732?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)